# how to add character with double so it works like methamatics java

Tags: java, double, character-arrays

i have two arraylists one is double name = numbers which store user input(double) and second is character name = operators which store input(+,-,*,/) entered by the user.
the code is below.
i want that when user enter a values the code should get the numbers value and do the operation entered in  operators.
please check the code below and tell me how to do it.

```
List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
List<Character> operators = new ArrayList<>();
........................

/* after getting input from user the code is now working as below.*/

void result() {
    et1.setText("");
    for (int i = 0; i < handler; i++) {
        double total2 = operators.get(i) + numbers.get(i);
        total3 += total2;
        et1.setText(Double.toString(total3));
    }

}
/*all values are just being add with eachother which are entered by the user.
help me how to solve this issue. */
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code presented doesn't even try to do what the problem statement requires it to do.

Comment: Of course your code just adds them up: That's what the code `total3 += total2;` does, and that's the only code you have. You have to read the operator from the user and take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically its not possible with the way you are doing like:

```
double total2= operators.get(i)+numbers.get(i);
```

You would need a switch with operators like:

```
switch (operators.get(i)) {
    case '+':
         //do add
         break;
    case '-':
         //subtract
         break
    blah blah...
}
```

Comment: Idea is Great let me try and if its work i'll obviously add vote for you Thanks almas

Comment: @Andriopak You are most welcome and Glad you liked the idea :)

Comment: i am not able to give you + vote dear because my reputation is low and i really wanted to give you + because it works for me

Comment: Hey It's ok. I am glad code above worked for you and that's enough for me.

Comment: thank you almas can we take each other skype address on this website or its not the rule?

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
void result() {

    et1.setText("");
    for (int i=0; i<handler;i++) {
        switch(operators.get(i)) {
            case '+':
                total3 += numbers.get(i);
                break;
            case '-':
                total3 -= numbers.get(i);
                break;
            case '*':
                total3 *= numbers.get(i);
                break;
            case '/':
                total3 /= numbers.get(i);
                break;
    et1.setText(Double.toString(total3));
    }           
}
```

That is not the best way to solve your problem. Read more about maps and lambdas that supported in java 8. Your map should be look like following (i know lambdas in c#, java must  have something similar. Sorry for my java). This way makes your code clean and extendable: you should not add more switches for add operators like ^ or % - just key/value pair to your map. Java mixed with c# code :/:

```
Map operations = HashMap<char, object>() { //in c# I use delegates instead object and i don't know type of lambda in java
{'+', (x, y) -> x + y},
{'-', (x, y) -> x - y},
{'*', (x, y) -> x * y},
{'/', (x, y) -> x / y},

}
total3 = operations.get(operators[i])(total3, total2);
```